# jQuery toggle running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.show_hide_login').toggle(
    function (){
            alert('show');
            $("div#fullpage").show();
            $("div#loginbox").show();
        },
  function (){
            alert('hide');
            $("div#loginbox").hide();
            $("div#fullpage").hide();
        }
  ); });
```

Any idea on why it would be running twice when I click on either link (two, one is a div and one is an anchor)?

Comment: Is it possible your script above is running twice? Put an alert *before* the `.toggle()` call to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 5):

How many elements do you have with the `.show_hide_login` class? I'll guess you have two of those. In which case, `$('.show_hide_login')` result contains two elements, and `toggle()` is executed for each of them.

Comment: I have a standard link: <a id="nav_login_register" class="show_hide_login" href="#">Login / Register</a>

Comment: and also a fullpage div overlay which is set to display:none. <div id="fullpage" class="show_hide_login"></div>

Comment: `.toggle()` with function parameters is just a click event. Unless the `.show_hide_login` elements are nested, it would only execute for the one that was clicked. :o)

Comment: Thanks, I've moved them out into separate .click events which works fine.. I guess that'll teach me for trying to cut corners :(

Comment: @Nathan - It looks to me like you're using `.toggle()` correctly. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrMXN/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question, but you could clean up your code a bit like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('.show_hide_login').toggle(
    function() {
        alert('show');
        $("#loginbox,#fullpage").show();
    }, function() {
        alert('hide');
        $("#loginbox,#fullpage").hide();
    });
});
```

As to your actual problem, I suspect Nick's guessed the culprit. Check out this demo to see the result of binding the same event twice: http://jsfiddle.net/9jPLv/

In addition to adding an alert prior to the binding of the toggle event, you could add in an `unbind()` and see if that solves the problem, like so:

```
$('.show_hide_login').unbind().toggle(
```

If that solves it, the toggle binding is definitely being run twice, so you'd just have to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

my answer is just a kind of checkpoint,i had the same issue but for different reason.  I did include the script file in base page as well as child page.  this resulted in toggle running twice if you have this problem check that the script is added only once.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the same issue i was having.

so if you got an element with a script tag in it - then you move that containing element or wrap it with another tag in jquery - then the ready function in jquery is executed again - thus binding a second toggle function to your element.

as suggested $('.show_hide_login').unbind().toggle( is a workaround that does work, but better to try moving your javascript code to the head or bottom of the page.